How can I force a Homebrew package reinstall
I'm running update/upgrade to Homebrew after months of ignoring it. I'm having problems getting rid of a package.
First tried brew update (all of these are partial logs):
==> Migrating cask git-credential-manager-core to git-credential-
Error: inreplace failed
/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/git-credential-manager/.metadata/2.0.785/20221103154004.876/Casks/git-credential-manager.rb:
expected replacement of /\A\s*cask\s+"git\-credential\-manager\-core"/ with "cask \"git-credential-manager\""

Then brew upgrade:
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package:
git-credential-manager 2.0.785 -> 2.5.1
==> Upgrading git-credential-manager-core
==> Downloading https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/releases
==> Downloading from https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-rel
######################################################################### 100.0%
==> Running uninstall script /opt/homebrew/share/gcm-core/uninstall.sh
==> Purging files for version 2.5.1 of Cask git-credential-manager
Error: git-credential-manager: uninstall script /opt/homebrew/share/gcm-core/uninstall.sh does not exist.

Then later did (complete log):
CTMacUser ~ % brew uninstall git-credential-manager-core
Warning: Formula microsoft/git/git-credential-manager-core was renamed to homebrew/cask/git-credential-manager.
Warning: Cask microsoft/git/git-credential-manager-core was renamed to git-credential-manager.
==> Uninstalling Cask git-credential-manager-core
==> Running uninstall script /opt/homebrew/share/gcm-core/uninstall.sh
Error: uninstall script /opt/homebrew/share/gcm-core/uninstall.sh does not exist.
CTMacUser ~ % brew uninstall git-credential-manager     
==> Uninstalling Cask git-credential-manager-core
==> Running uninstall script /opt/homebrew/share/gcm-core/uninstall.sh
Error: uninstall script /opt/homebrew/share/gcm-core/uninstall.sh does not exist.

How do I get rid of something whose uninstall routine is fried? (Then I could reinstall.)

You can use this for cleanup and reinstalling:
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies <package_name>
brew install <package_name>

If you want to force reinstall all outdated packages, you can use:
brew upgrade --force-bottle

Also you can delete the package manually from /opt/homebrew/share

All 3 of these produced the same results:
==> Running uninstall script /opt/homebrew/share/gcm-core/uninstall.sh
==> Purging files for version 2.5.1 of Cask git-credential-manager
Error: git-credential-manager: uninstall script /opt/homebrew/share/gcm-core/uninstall.sh does not exist.
Is there a way to list all my deliberately installed packages? So I can incinerate my entire homebrew install and start over. Is deleting the “/opt/homebrew” directory how I can remove homebrew without going through its scripts?

@CTMacUser Yes you can delete it via: /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)" 
i don't recommend force deleting it from /opt/homebrew/*
